# Solving for a variable in the norm

Tags: linear-algebra

How do we solve for l in the following equation:

$$R_m = A \log_2\left(1 + \frac{C}{\|x_m - l\|^2}\right)$$

Comment: You won't have a unique solution,  you'll have all the points that are the appropriate distance from $x_m$,  so a (hyper)sphere

Comment: Any point on a "circle" of radius $\frac{C}{2^{R_m/A}-1}$ centered about $x_m$ will solve this equation.

Comment: @user429040 Do you mean any point inside the circle ?

Comment: @Paulo no, I don't.